# How to get hold of Amazon MySQL RDS certificates

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Amazon RDS documentation (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#53) specifies that "Amazon RDS generates an SSL certificate for each [MySQL] DB Instance". I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to find the certificates and the certificates are nowhere to be found in the management console.

Where are the certificates?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=62110.

- Download ca cert file from here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem

`curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem`

- Connect to mysql:

```sh
mysql -uusername -p --host=host --ssl-ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

- Check that your connection is really encrypted:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
```

```
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | AES256-SHA |
+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

- Optionally force SSL for a specific user to connect to MySQL

`mysql> ALTER USER 'username'@'host|%' REQUIRE SSL`

Comment: For those who may run into the same problem, the path to my .pem file failed as long as I had a ~ (e.g. ~/Downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem). Had to do --ssl_ca=/Users/myusername/Downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem. Error with ~ was: ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation

Comment: The certificate from Amazon expired on April 4, 2015, and I cannot see any updates. If anyone has the new URL, please share.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the cert from this address: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Answer (score 5):

You can get the AWS RDS certificate file information from the AWS Documentation guide itself

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html

Download the certificate from here

https://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem

Update - Amazon updated the SSL certificate, you can download the it from here :  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

Use the following command to login into mysql

```
root@sathish:/usr/src# mysql -h awssathish.xxyyzz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u awssathish -p --ssl-ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 5.6.13-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> 
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ‘awssathish’@’%’ REQUIRE SSL
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
mysql> 
mysql> show variables like "%ssl";
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_openssl  | YES   |
| have_ssl      | YES   |
+---------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> 
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | AES256-SHA |
+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

Where

**awssathish.xxyyzz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com**

is Endpoint of RDS,

**awssathish**

is the username of the rds server

Comment: The certificate expired on April 4, 2015. If anyone has a new certificate URL, please share.

Comment: added new SSL certificate link.

Answer (score 1):

I used http://aws-blog.io/2016/rds-over-ssl/ 
You have to get root pem and pem for the region and concatenate 2 files in one.
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-us-west-2.pem
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem

And merge files to have single rds-ca-2015-us-west-2-bundle.pem file.
With --ssl-ca provide full path to you pem file.