# Why am I seeing "SSL connection error" when trying to connect to RDS from EC2 (both on us-west)?

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've created a new multi-AZ RDS instance on **us-west** and added the private and public IP addresses of one of my EC2 instances (also on us-west) to its security group.

I try to connect via the following `mysql` command:

```
mysql -h [RDS Endpoint] -P 3306 -u admin -p
```

But I see the following error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error
```

It turns out that the RDS instance happens to be in the **us-west-1c** availability zone, while the EC2 instance I tried connecting from is in **us-west-1b**. So, I tried connecting from a different EC2 instance in 1c and sure enough, that worked.

*But* when I attempted the same thing with us-west-1b—i.e., creating an RDS instance on 1b and then trying to connect to it from an EC2 instance on 1b—that *didn't* work.

So:

```
EC2 Instance AZ | RDS Instance AZ | Success?
----------------+-----------------+---------
us-west-1c      | us-west-1c      | Yes
us-west-1b      | us-west-1c      | No
us-west-1b      | us-west-1b      | No
```

I'm really scratching my head on this one. I apologize if this question was a bit hard to follow; really I'm just hoping that someone else has encountered this same issue and figured it out already. If so, please share your hard-earned knowledge!

Comment: Have you checked your grants to see from what hosts usage is allowed?  These two questions seem to be related:  http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#53

Comment: @AJ.: Yeah, and in fact that admin user is granted all privileges from "%" (so all hosts, right?). I checked this using `show grants`; is that what you meant?

Comment: k - next, have you tried specifying the CA Cert with:  `--ssl-ca=path_to_mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem`?  Check this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463577/how-to-get-hold-of-amazon-mysql-rds-certificates  It could be that the EC2 hosts in 1c have the (updated?) CA cert installed already but that they don't in 1b.

Comment: @AJ.: Tried that as well—no dice :(

Comment: Instead of adding the IP addresses to the RDS security group, did you try adding the EC2 security group name (there are two types of entries) ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque: Yes, I did try that as well. Nothing seems to work; I just keep getting "ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error" no matter what.